# Forwarding messages from one ActiveMQ to another?

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, activemq-classic, broker

I am trying to setup a simple network of ActiveMQ brokers. I have 2 machines,  say A and B.

In A's `activemq.xml` file I have put networkConnector which has URI pointed to machine B. 
In the logs of A it is shown that it is connected to B.

I have an application which sends messages to A. In ActiveMQ's web-console in the *Network* tab I can see my messages being enqueued and also dequeued (which I presume means messages are forwarded to machine B).

My question is on which queues/topic the messages are forwarded? Should they be the same queue/topic (i.e. name) as of machine A.

I have a consumer which is listening on machine B on destination name as same as of machine A, but it is not getting messages. Since the messages are shown to be dequeued that means messages are getting to machine B. Also I have changed log level to DEBUG but I couldnt make sense out of the logs.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to setup a network of brokers: http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html
The subscriptions are forwarded across the brokers in the network of brokers. 
The messages will be forwarded to the same topics/queues.
It seems either your message is not forwarded or the subscription is not.

Have you checked that your consumer is listed in the consumer list?
Is it possible to get the configuration file of the broker?